# Replace all _'s with - before query string using REGEX in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying create an `.htaccess` rewrite rule using regex to replace all instances of `_` with `-` in a URL prior to the `?`. The expression should not impact the query string, just the URL.

For example, this:

```
/north_america/united_states/california/?search=1&location=ca_orange_county&city=buena_park  
/united_states/california/?search=1&location=ca_orange_county&city=buena_park  
/united_states/south_carolina/?add-place=place_name  
/canada/british_columbia/bc/?search=1&city=vancouver
/add_listing/?listing_type=place&package_id=12
```

Would be replaced with:

```
/north-america/united-states/california/?search=1&location=ca_orange_county&city=buena_park  
/united-states/california/?search=1&location=ca_orange_county&city=buena_park  
/united-states/south-carolina/?add-place=place_name  
/canada/british-columbia/bc/?search=1&city=vancouver  
/add-listing/?listing_type=place&package_id=12
```

Comment: What's happening with `dir_search` in your example output? That doesn't follow your requirement rule.

Comment: My bad... Corrected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a single regex can't do it. I'm not sure if rewrite rules offers some magic about limiting the scope to the url and not the querystring allowing a simple /_/-/g to work.

Comment: not to my knowledge. @TommiKyntola.

Answer (score 0):

To get the underscores to hyphens in the URL:

```
RewriteRule /?(\w*)_(\w*)/ /$1-$2/
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/iO9vC0/)

Comment: Thanks, can I throw a hitch at you?

    /north_america/united-states/california/?search=1&location=ca_orange_county&city=buena_park  

So no matter what precedes the ?, no matter how many levels deep the dir, it has to replace all _'s

PS.  Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It's super close. I don't know why in some cases it's returning //'s in the path.  Thoughts?

I just updated the question examples.

Comment: in which cases is it failing and what is the erroneous result, please. I've updated the demo with your newest target set.

Answer (score 0):

To replace all underscores by hyphen in a **single redirect** you can use these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+([^_]*_+.*)$ $1-$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless %{QUERY_STRING} is in RewriteCond, then RewriteRule won't affect querystring. Thus a simple recursive rule should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [N]
```

It matches:

- any number of non-underscores (reference $1, may be empty)
- one underscore
- the rest (reference $1, may be empty)
- And [N flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) is used to recurse the rewrite rules, and once all underscores have been changed this rule will no longer match, because the underscore there is obligatory for matching and then recursion breaks